# Which changes does a RethinkDB proxy node receive?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a RethinkDB cluster with thousands of changefeed subscribers and the load from the subscriptions is pretty high, so I'm looking into proxy nodes. One question I have is which changes each proxy node receives, or put differently, is there any benefit in trying to cluster similar subscriptions on specific proxy nodes?

The concrete situation is that I have one table with two relevant fields for this discussion: an account field and a topic field. The subscriptions filter by account and do a "between" two topics to get a topic prefix. The table has a compound secondary index on account and topic, so the filter really is an index range scan.

What I'm wondering is whether breaking the table up into a table by account would help with subscriptions. This would only be the case if I could direct all subscriptions for an account to one proxy and if at the RethinkDB level that proxy then would not receive changes for tables for which it has no subscription. Is that the case or does each proxy receive all changes?